# Copy all text in a LibreOffice Draw drawing

Tags: libreoffice-draw

I have a large flowchart, created in LibreOffice Draw (3.3.1), that I would like to copy all of the text from. I do not need, nor care about the order or structure, I just need all of the text from within the blocks.

I can't seem to find any way to export without turning it into an image, and none of the "Paste Special" options allow me to get unformatted text.

Is there a way to do this without retyping everything?

Comment: Hmm, superuser keeps correcting the "draw" tag to "drawing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not direct, you could try:

- Export drawing as ***PDF***
- Open it in PDF viewer
- Select All (*CTRL+A*)
- Copy selected text to any text editor

Comment: I had assumed exporting as a PDF would also convert it to an image, but it *does* retain the text on top of the objects. Thanks!